# Pull in all child libraries of a library/module/theme with dependencies in yml

Tags: 8

I have one contrib module and a custom module. The contrib module defines a lot of sub libraries and I want to depend all of it. Example:

Contrib module module_contrib.libraries.yml

```
module_contrib_lib: [...]
module_contrib_lib.sub1: [...]
module_contrib_lib.sub2: [...]
module_contrib_lib.sub3: [...]
module_contrib_lib.sub4: [...]
module_contrib_lib.sub5: [...]
module_contrib_lib.sub6: [...]
[...]
```

And in my  custom.libraries.yml

```
custom:
  [...]
  dependencies:
    - module_contrib/module_contrib_lib
```

But this doesn't pull in the subs, I tried with `- module_contrib/module_contrib_lib.*`, but it doesn't do anything. If I put `- module_contrib/module_contrib_lib.sub1` ect it works. There's no any wildchar to pull in all of the sub libs?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I suppose if you want to pull them all in, you can nest them under 1 library definition.

Or, add another library definition that contains all of the resources, so you can still use multiple or the whole shebang if you want to.

Comment: so there's no other way, because I don't want to edit or patch the contrib module, but if it has a new library in that case I want to use that too, because it will depend automatically my module for that too...